# Selecting a certain item in your css HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have 4 images, and I want to select each one so I can change each images height and width.

I tried to use img:nth-of-type(3) to select the 3rd image to change the size, but nothing happened. I want to move the height and the width from inline coding to an external CSS File.

How would I select a certain image?

```css
figure{
    padding:2em;
    margin-left: 3em;
    margin-bottom:2em;
}

img:nth-of-type(3) {
    height:50em;
    width:50em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
    figure{
        margin-left:8em;
    }

}
```

```html
    <div>
        <figure>
            <img src="images/ACE.png" height="150em">
            <figcaption data-title="Certification History" certification="yes">Certified Personal Trainer</figcaption>
        </figure>
  
        <figure>
            <img src="images/NSCA.png" height="150em" >
            <figcaption data-title="Certification History" certification="yes">CSCS - Certified Strength</figcaption><figcaption>and Conditioning Specialist</figcaption>
        </figure>
   
        <figure>
            <img src="images/USA.png" height="150em" width="125em">
            <figcaption data-title="Certification History" certification="yes">National E License</figcaption>
        </figure> 
  
        <figure>
            <img src="images/Functional-movement.jpg" height="150em" width="200em">
            <figcaption data-title="Certification History" certification="yes">Functional Movement Sceen Level 1</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nth-of-type(3) approach will work, but you will need to target the `figure` element  with that and then the image within it. The reason is that for each figure there  is only one img - so you never get to the third one you want - so you need to target the third figure element and then style the image contained in it.

**Note that I have amended the styling to target the 3rd figure and then the image with it**. I also put a red border around the image to demonstrate it has been targetted.

```css
figure{
    padding:2em;
    margin-left: 3em;
    margin-bottom:2em;
}

figure:nth-of-type(3) img {
    height:50em;
    width:50em;
    border: solid 1px red
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
    figure{
        margin-left:8em;
    }

}
```

```html
<div>
        <figure>
            <img src="images/ACE.png" height="150em">
            <figcaption data-title="Certification History" certification="yes">Certified Personal Trainer</figcaption>
        </figure>
  
        <figure>
            <img src="images/NSCA.png" height="150em" >
            <figcaption data-title="Certification History" certification="yes">CSCS - Certified Strength</figcaption><figcaption>and Conditioning Specialist</figcaption>
        </figure>
   
        <figure>
            <img src="images/USA.png" height="150em" width="125em">
            <figcaption data-title="Certification History" certification="yes">National E License</figcaption>
        </figure> 
  
        <figure>
            <img src="images/Functional-movement.jpg" height="150em" width="200em">
            <figcaption data-title="Certification History" certification="yes">Functional Movement Sceen Level 1</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
```